# Problem with jQuery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery cycle pluging, and having some trouble after i added a play/pause option.

The code looks like this;

```
        $('#img').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 1000,
            pager: '.imagegallerypager.r2s1',
            pagerClick: function (zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) {
                $('#txt').cycle({
                    startingSlide: zeroBasedSlideIndex
                });
                $('#txt').cycle('pause');
                $('#img').cycle('pause');

            }
        });

        $('#txt').cycle({
            fx: 'none',
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 1000
        });

        $('#playpause, .imagegallerypager a').click(function () {
            if ($('#playpause').attr('class') == 'pause') {
                $('#txt').cycle('pause');
                $('#img').cycle('pause');
                $('#playpause').html('<img src="images/icon_play.gif" alt="Play" title="Play" />');
                $('#playpause').removeClass('pause');
                $('#playpause').addClass('play');
            }
            else if ($(this).attr('class') == 'play') {
                $('#txt').cycle('resume');
                $('#img').cycle('resume');
                $('#playpause').html('<img src="images/icon_pause.gif" alt="Pause" title="Pause" />');
                $('#playpause').removeClass('play');
                $('#playpause').addClass('pause');
            }
        });
```

The script runs fine until i press the pause button and then the play button to start the action again. The img runs fine, but the txt seems to have the settings reset (ie fx effet, timeout effect etc) resulting in the img and txt being ofset and no longer following each other. I have tried many different things, but so far no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unrelated, but checking `.attr('class') == ...` is not as good as checking `.hasClass(...)`. Don't forget the tag may have multiple classes, and a `==` comparison will not always work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work perfectly fine here, although I've had to amend your code to use .hasClass() because checking the 'class' attribute isn't reliable (jQuery leaves spaces in the class name).

Here's the code I tried using:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Example Slideshow</title>
<style type="text/css">
.slideshow { height: 232px; width: 232px; margin: auto }
.slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js"></script>

<!--  initialize the slideshow when the DOM is ready -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 'slow',
    timeout: 1000,
    pager: '.imagegallerypager.r2s1',
    pagerClick: function (zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) {
        $('#txt').cycle({
            startingSlide: zeroBasedSlideIndex
        });
        $('#txt').cycle('pause');
        $('#img').cycle('pause');

    }
});

$('#txt').cycle({
    fx: 'none',
    speed: 'slow',
    timeout: 1000
});

$('#playpause').click(function () {
console.log('test');
    if ($('#playpause').hasClass('pause')) {
        $('#txt').cycle('pause');
        $('#img').cycle('pause');
        $('#playpause').html('play');
        $('#playpause').removeClass('pause');
        $('#playpause').addClass('play');
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('play')) {
        $('#txt').cycle('resume');
        $('#img').cycle('resume');
        $('#playpause').html('pause');
        $('#playpause').removeClass('play');
        $('#playpause').addClass('pause');
    }
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slideshow" id="img">
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div id="txt">
   <span>one</span>
   <span>two</span>
   <span>three</span>
   <span>four</span>
   <span>five</span>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="playpause" class="pause">pause</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But your example does not include a pager - it is this code that messes up my script;

Comment: pagerClick: function (zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) {
                    $('#txt').cycle({
                        startingSlide: zeroBasedSlideIndex
                    });
                    $('#txt').cycle('pause');
                    $('#img').cycle('pause');

                }

Comment: Try adding this div to the bottom of the html; <div class="imagegallerypager r2s1"></div>

when you click a number in the pager, click the play/pause button (twice in this case), you will see that the image will resume normaly but the text will be set to default options?